# How can we add loader in clarity framework in div as we can add in Datagrid attribute [clrDgLoading]="loading" to add loader

Tags: loader, vmware-clarity

How can we add loader in clarity framework in div tag as we can add in `Datagrid` attribute `[clrDgLoading]="loading"` to add loader?

Answer (score 1):

Clarity has a spinner component, the detailed documentation is available here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/spinners

Answer (score 1):

Set the [clrDgLoading] property in template like below.

```
<clr-datagrid [clrDgLoading]="loading">
```

In Component.ts initialize the "loading" property to true. Then after data loaded from the data service, set the "loading" property to false.

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  loading = true;
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService
      .getData()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        // your code
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```